# Decrypting an already encrypted String

Tags: java

I have a project where I must encrypt a string, then decrypt it.  The encrypting part I got, but I cant find a way to decrypt it.

Encypting file

```
file = Input.readFile("txt.txt").toUpperCase();

ArrayList<String>  mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); 
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA1"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB1"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC1"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD1");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA2"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB2"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC2"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD2");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA3"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB3"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC3"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD3");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA4"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB4"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC4"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD4");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA5"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB5"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC5"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD5");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA6"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB6"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC6"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD6");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA7"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB7"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC7"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD7");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA8"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB8"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC8"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD8");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA9"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB9"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC9"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD9");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAA"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBA"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCA"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDA");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAB"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBB"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCB"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDB");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAD"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBD"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCD"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDD");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAE"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBE"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCE"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDE");

//Encypt
//going backwards
 for(int i = file.length();  i > 0 ; i--){
    index ++;
    //shuffle the list 
    //Collections.shuffle(mylist);
    char symbol = file.charAt(file.length() - index);

    //change the ascii number by 1-10
    int ascii = ((int)symbol); 

    //if ascii is between A-Z or a-z display a card
    if( ((ascii >= (int)'A' && ascii <= (int)'Z'))) { 
      build += mylist.get(ascii - 65); 
    }
    //if the ascii number is divisible by 2, display a 0, if not a 1 
    else{
    if(ascii % 2 == 0){
      build += 0;
    }else{
      build += 1;
    }

    }
 }
 try{
   Files.write(Paths.get("encryptedFile.txt"), build.getBytes());
 }catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Oh NO!");
 }

System.out.println("\nYour encrypted message is: \n" + build);
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------\t");
//End Encypt
```

Decrypting

```
String file = Input.readFile("encryptedFile.txt");

String password = "",build2="";

ArrayList<String>  mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); 
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA1"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB1"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC1"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD1");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA2"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB2"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC2"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD2");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA3"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB3"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC3"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD3");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA4"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB4"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC4"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD4");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA5"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB5"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC5"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD5");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA6"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB6"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC6"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD6");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA7"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB7"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC7"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD7");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA8"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB8"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC8"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD8");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA9"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB9"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC9"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD9");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAA"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBA"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCA"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDA");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAB"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBB"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCB"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDB");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAD"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBD"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCD"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDD");
mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAE"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBE"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCE"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDE"); 

  build2 = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < file.length(); i++){
    char symbol = file.charAt(i);
    int ascii = ((int)symbol); 

    int pos = mylist.indexOf(); 
    build2 += pos + ",";


  }

  System.out.println("\nYour decrypted message is: \n" + build2);

try{
   Files.write(Paths.get("dencryptedFile.txt"), build2.getBytes());
 }catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Oh NO!");
 }
//End Decypt
```

Right now the original file is

> "A B C"

when it encrypts it turns into

> "00"

I would like the

> "00"

to turn back into

> "A B C"

But I can't figure out how.

https://repl.it/@MatthewZeman/EncryptionCode - encryption
https://repl.it/@MatthewZeman/DecryptionCode - decryption

Comment: Did you step through your code with a debugger already?

Comment: Do you have to write your own encryption algorithm as part of the project? Because if it's not a requirement, [don't be a Dave](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/915)

Comment: Yes I did , it has to be original @MikeTheLiar

Comment: Note that you don't specify any encoding when reading or writing the file. Thus the default encoding (most likely the platform encoding) will be used and since that can differ you are bound to run into problems. Try specifying an encoding like UTF-8 whereever you read a file or convert between strings and bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find the working code with explanations in the comments.

```
import java.util.*;

class EncryptDecrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // List to convert ascii characters to cards
        ArrayList<String>  mylist = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA1"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB1");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC1"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD1");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA2"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB2");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC2"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD2");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA3"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB3");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC3"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD3");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA4"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB4"); 
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC4"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD4");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA5"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB5"); 
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC5"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD5");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA6"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB6");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC6"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD6");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA7"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB7");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC7"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD7");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA8"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB8"); 
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC8"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD8");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCA9"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCB9");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCC9"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCD9");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAA"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBA"); 
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCA"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDA");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAB"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBB"); 
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCB"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDB");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAD"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBD"); 
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCD"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDD");
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCAE"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCBE"); 
        mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCCE"); mylist.add("\uD83C\uDCDE");

        // Example string (can be read from file if needed)
        String text = "A B C";

        // The encrypted string
        String encrypted = "";

        // Encrypt
        // Note: You can use "i" instead of using another variable "index"
        for(int i = 0;  i < text.length() ; i++){

            // Get next character from text (or file)
            char symbol = text.charAt(i);

            // Convert character to int
            int ascii = ((int)symbol); 

            //if ascii is between A-Z or a-z display a card
            if( ((ascii >= (int)'A' && ascii <= (int)'Z'))) { 
                encrypted += mylist.get(ascii - 65); 
            } else if(ascii % 2 == 0) { // Using "else if" here makes the code much cleaner
                encrypted += "0"; // Here you should append a character "0" instead of the integer 0
            } else{
                encrypted += "1"; // Here you should append a character "1" instead of the integer 1
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nYour encrypted message is: \n" + encrypted);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------\t");

        // The decrypted text
        String decrypted = "";

        // Decrypting this is a little more difficult for multiple reasons.
        // 1. The cards are 2 character symbols. Meaning we have to check if the next character is a card or not
        // 2. Then, once we know if it is a card or not, we need to take apropriate action
        // 3. Inherently we loose some information while encrypting. Therefore we will never get back the exact same string

        // Storage to store one character if we encounter a card
        String charStore = "";

        // Loop through text
        for(int i = 0; i < encrypted.length(); i++){

            // Get next character
            char nextChar = encrypted.charAt(i);
            if(charStore.length() == 0) {
                // Our character store is empty, so we check what the next character is
                if(nextChar == "0".charAt(0)) {
                    // We found our next character to be a "0". So we convert it to a space
                    // This is where we lost information. we don't know exactly which character was here before
                    decrypted += " ";
                } else if (nextChar == "1".charAt(0)) {
                    // We found our next character to be a "1". So we convert it to a !
                    // This is where we also lost information. we don't know exactly which character was here before
                    decrypted += "!";
                } else {
                    // The character is neither a "0" nor a "1", so it has to be part of a chard, which is 2 characters in length
                    // We store the current character in our storage "charStore"
                    charStore += nextChar;
                }

            } else {
                // Our character store contained at least one character. 
                // So we can safely assume that together with the next character we have a card symbol
                // Concatenate stored and current character
                charStore += nextChar;
                // Search for the card in the list
                // Remember that you subtracted 65 from previously, so we have to add 65 here.
                // Also: You forgot the argument inside the "indexOf" in your code
                decrypted += (char)(mylist.indexOf(charStore) + 65);
                // Reset the character store
                charStore = "";
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nYour decrypted message is: \n" + decrypted);


    }
}
```